# Trouble passing in function parameter in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Right now, users on our MVC web app can make a bunch of ajax calls to the server. Currently we're handling them all uniquely without a global wrapper/handler method. I'd like to change that, but I don't have much experience with function delegates in C#.

Ideally, I'd like for it to be designed something like below:

```
public class GenericService
{
    public PageViewModel EditPage(PageViewModel model)
    {
        ....
    }

    public JsonResult JsonAjaxRequest(Func<Object, Object> serviceCall, Object data)
    {
        try
        {
            return new JsonResult() { Data = new { status = "ok", data = serviceCall(data) } };
        }
        catch
        {
            return new JsonResult() { Data = new { status = "error", message = "The server encountered an unknown error." } };
        }
    }
```

Now in my controller, I have the following code:

```
private readonly GenericService _service;

public JsonResult PageEdit(PageViewModel model)
{
    return Json(_service.JsonAjaxRequest(x=>_service.EditPage(model), model));
}
```

I keep getting a `cannot convert from method group to system.func<object, object>` error and an `invalid arguments` compile error and I'm not sure why. Please advise.

Comment: Any generic type parameter that uses `Object` defeats the point of using generics.

Comment: @Oded What do you propose using instead, in this case?  Would you suggest that he create his own delegate type that accepts an object and returns an object, because if he did I'd suggest he use `Func` instead.

Comment: @Servy - Not sure generics are the right answer here at all.

Comment: @Oded My question still stands.  What would you propose using instead?  I see no preferable alternative, other than possibly making the method generic and using `T` instead of `object`, but the code he's using here ought to work.

Comment: @Jay, I can't replicate this issue.  Are you sure that's the code that you're using?

Comment: Could you add the code where you're passing a method group argument to `JsonAjaxRequest` and the type of the method?

Comment: I can't see exactly what line gives you the error you quote. You are using `Func<in T, out TResult>` type. For a method to be compatible with it, the method must take in one parameter which must be of type `Object` (there are no base classes or interfaces on `Object`, so it must be `Object` exactly). And it must return something (not `void`), and it must be a type which is convertible to `Object`, but all types are convertible to `Object`, so there's no restriction on the return type (except it can't be `void` like I said). Edit: Return type must not be a value type, though.

Comment: I think @Jeppe has it.  `EditPage` must return `void` for this to not work.

Comment: @Servy I just changed the names of the methods and got rid of the actual service code. For some reason it wouldn't compile for me. There was a deleted answer below that suggested putting in `JsonAjaxRequest<T>(Func<T, Object> serviceCall, T data);` and that actually worked for me.

Comment: @Servy There are some details. If return type of method `M` is a value type, it is OK to say `Func<object, object> f = o => M(o);`, but in that case `Func<object, object> f = M;` will not work. But the error message seems like a method group conversion, not a lambda conversion, but we see no method group conversion in the code.

Comment: @JaySun My guess is the code you posted here is different from your real code in some key way, and the change worked for that reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest changing your method so that it is generic, rather than just using `object` everywhere:

```
public JsonResult JsonAjaxRequest<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn, TOut> serviceCall, TIn data)
{
    try
    {
        return new JsonResult() { Data = new { status = "ok", data = serviceCall(data) } };
    }
    catch
    {
        return new JsonResult() { Data = new { status = "error", message = "The server encountered an unknown error." } };
    }
}
```

Using this the generic arguments can be inferred based on the lambda or method group you provide as a parameter.  For a lambda it shouldn't be an issue, but when passing in a method group directly it can help with a few edge cases.  It also means that the parameter you provide to the function is strongly typed, so you don't need to cast it.

The only way that you could get a compiler error like the one you mentioned after making this change would be if you used a method that either accepts some number of parameters other than one (namely zero or 2+) or if it returns `void` instead of some value.